# Util creating a list synchronized on a specified mutex

Tags: java, list, concurrency, synchronized

Is there some util creating a list synchronized on a specified mutex? Like `java.util.Collections.synchronizedList(List<T> list, Object mutex)` but public?

Comment: Why do you think that you need that?

Comment: Needed implementing some complex operations (besides insertion and deletion), and they must be also atomic against other list modifying operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such `public` method that will allow you to control the mutex that the synchronized collection will use. So if it’s not the list which allows you to specify the mutex, your higher level operations have to be implemented with that flexibility, e.g.:

```
public static <T> boolean addIfNew(List<T> target, T value, Object mutex) {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        return !target.contains(value) && target.add(value);
    }
}
```

which can then be used as

```
List<String> synchedList=Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
addIfNew(synchedList, "foo", synchedList);
```

This works because the list returned by `synchronizedList` will use itself as mutex. Compare with [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-):

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

> It is imperative that the user manually **synchronize on the returned list** when iterating over it:
>
> ```
>  List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
>      ...
>  synchronized (list) {
>      Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>      while (i.hasNext())
>          foo(i.next());
>  }
> ```

The reason why the implementation allows using different mutex objects internally is that you can create [*sub lists*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) and the sub list of a synchronized list will synchronize on the backing list instance rather than itself (same applies to `Vector.subList`). So when you pass a sub list to your high-level method, it’s crucial to pass the original synchronized list as mutex.

Similar things apply to the `Collection` view to maps:

[`Collections.synchronizedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-):

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when iterating over any of its collection views:
>
> ```
> Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
>     ...
> Set s = m.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
>     ...
> synchronized (m) {  // Synchronizing on m, not s!
>     Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>     while (i.hasNext())
>         foo(i.next());
> }
> ```

---

There is a simplification to this. If you ensure that all access to a collection takes place in your methods, these methods may agree on an arbitrary mutex and be thread-safe if synchronizing on that mutex consistently. Of course, there is no need for the collection itself to do an additional synchronization itself then, but that’s what it is all about:

In practice, you will hardly find any useful scenario for these synchronized collections. Any non-trival operation requires more than one access to a collection thus requiring manual or higher-level synchronization which renders the low-level synchronization obsolete.

It’s tempting to think about passing a synchronized collection to an arbitrary method working with a collection and gain thread safety automatically without additional synchronization but since this works only if said method consist of one single access to the collection, you won’t find any useful real life method for which that works.

So the bottom line is you will always have to make *your* code thread safe and controlling access to collections and thus never have a real need for a synchronized collection.